# angularjs parse syntax error when splitting a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that replaces mysql date time string to just month and date. but it is giving me parse syntax error.

Directive:

```
directiveApp.directive('cleanDate',function(){

    var monthName = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sept","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        template: '{{mon}} {{date}}',
        scope: {
            timeset: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            console.log(scope.timeset);
            var t = scope.timeset.split(/[- :]/);
            console.log(t);
            if (parseInt(t[0]) != 0 && parseInt(t[1])!=0 && parseInt(t[2])!=0){
                var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
                scope.mon = monthName[d.getMonth()];
                scope.date = d.getDate();
            }
            else{
                scope.mon = '';
                scope.date='';
            }

        }
    };
```

Directive Test:

```
describe('getDistance Directive',function(){
     var $scope,$compile,template;
      beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_){
          $scope = _$rootScope_;
          $compile = _$compile_;    
      }));

    it ('Check Clean Date',function(){
        var element = "<clean-date timeset='2015-01-20 11:17:32'></clean-date>";

        template = $compile(element)($scope);
        $scope.$digest();
        expect(template.html()).toBe('January 20');
    });
  });
```

But this test responds with parse syntax error

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '11' is an unexpected token at column 12 of the expression [2015-01-20 11:17:32] starting at [11:17:32].
```

I am using the same code in one of my ionic project and it works fine, but transferring over to angularjs v1.2.28 is giving me a headache. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `scope: {timeset='='}`(called isolateBinding) the attribute value that we specify for `timeset` will be treated as a variableName defined in scope.

As `2015-01-20 11:17:32` is not a valid javascript variable name, parser thrown the error.

How we should be using:

```
//define a scope variable 
$scope.time = "2015-01-20 11:17:32";

var element = "<clean-date timeset='time'></clean-date>";
```

Read more on the angular isolateBindings at: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Answer (score 0):

You could do as @vinay-k suggests, or you could change your directive to use an attribute value instead of data-binding (since you're using the value only to initialize you directive):

```
directiveApp.directive('cleanDate',function(){
    [...]
    return {
        [...]
        scope: {
            timeset: '@'
        },
        [...]
    };
});
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
<clean-date timeset="2015-01-20 11:17:32"></clean-date>
<clean-date timeset="{{timeVarFromScope}}"></clean-date>
```

Or you could go even further an accept both using $scope.eval! For instance:

```
directiveApp.directive('cleanDate',function(){
    [...]
    return {
        scope: {
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            try {
                scope.timeset = scope.$eval(attr.timeset);
            } catch (e) {
                scope.timeset = attr.timeset;
            }
            [...]
        }
   };
});
```

Although that's not as pretty...

Comment: What is set to NaN? scope.timeset?